# How to set Profit taker order from Limit to Market in bracket orders?

Tags: interactive-brokers

When I setup my bracket order in Interactive brokers, my Profit taker order is set to Limit by default. I want something like, when a market touches my limit price, I immediately want that order to sell/buy to the market. The problem is sometimes, I dont get filled, even if the market touches my profit taker limit price and get stuck into a trade and my profit suffers.

Do let me know if someone has a good idea.

Market if touched(MIT) is not an option coz, 
Example: Let say at 9:30, market touched a price $56.30. I entered into a long trade with bracket order as follows: (Buy STOP: $55.10, Sell Profit taker, Market if touched @$56.30, Stop Loss: $53.40), As soon as my parent Buy STOP order is filled @$55.10, my Profit taker will get triggered, coz market already touched $56.30 in the morning and I will get filled at $55.11 or something as my profit taker.